# using the attrib command

Tags: windows, attributes

I'll try again. If it vague pleae explain why.

I am trying to use the attrib command in the c.l.i. format.

I need to find all files from all directories on my u.s.b.drive (I:) at the same time I need the output of this information to pause between screens.

This needs to be done in one command prompt.

The problem i am having is the pause part of the question.

when using the dir command a simple parameter /p takes care of the pause but no in the attrib command

Comment: Vague, yes, because you've given us absolutely no context about what you're talking about. No languages, no platforms.

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser.com

Comment: sounds clear to me

Answer (score 3):

You can send the output of DOS command through the 'more' utility, whose job is to send its input to the standard output (screen) one page at a time with a 'more' prompt to take you to the next page. This operation is called 'piping' and to do what you want, you use the pipe symbol: | (a vertical bar, possibly broken in the middle depending on your display character set and keyboard logos). To do what you want, try your attrib command like this:

```
attrib | more
```

On my keyboard, the pipe symbol is above the backslash:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try attribute commands in folder names with spaces, such as:

```
Folder Name = My Folder

disable hidden attributes for My Folder - Folder

attrib -h -s "My Folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all files and directories:

```
dir I:\*.* /s /a /p
```

That lists all files, no matter the attribute or subfolder. If you are ok not using the ATTRIB command, this is what you're looking for. It can also display the attributes with the command shown on Windows XP/Vista/7